# Which machine learning algorithm do I need in this scenario?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm developing a software with my friend in university, and the problem is: We are new to AI because they never taught us AI courses, we'll have them next year I think.

Our professor advised us to search about the algorithm before we start, and to give him what we found so we can use it, and I want to find what is good. We are making this software with Machine learning and here's what we want to have: Suppose I have 100 students report cards, and you want to classify them from the best to the worst, but with Machine learning.

it appeared in the exercice, that i need by "marks" and "opinions" of the professors who did the report cards ,and also the "class", that i need to show to other professors in the software who is best and worst but with the caracteristic they have exemple :

student 1 : 10 in maths 19 in science

student 2 : 10 in science 19 in maths

student 3 : 10 in science 19 in maths but is in lower class than student 2

the professor of science will see first student 1 ten studient 2

professor of maths will see first student 2 then student 3 then 1

What algorithm do we need and why? We have read a lot about machine learning algorithms, but I don't know what is the best to use in this case.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Sarah. Welcome to SO. Your question is not about programming and I suggest you post it rather at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: hey, thank you , and  sorry because i don't know much of this stuff , i will post it there .
Thanks again

Comment: No problem. And good luck solving your task.

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on the data you have and what exactly you want to predict.

Are the features continuous or categorical? Do you want to predict a continouus or categorical value?

Let´s assume that you have categorical features in your report cards and you want to predict a binary target like "best" or "worst", than look into binary classification. If you need to predict grades (eg. 1 or 2 or 3 etc.) than look into categorical classification.

If you want to sort all the report cards by estimating a continuous value than you need regression.

For all these you have a wide variety of algorithms like Linear Regression, Decision Trees, Random Forests, Naive Bayes, Support Vector Machines or even Neural Networks.

Have a look here at this [helpful scikit-learn estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) to get a first intuition of your choices.

[This cheat sheet from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-algorithm-choice) is very good too.

From what I can derive from your question I would first check a simple Linear Regression.

Comment: thanks , it appeared now in the exercice, that i need by "marks" and "opinions" of the professors who did the report cards ,and also the class, that i need to show to other professors in the software who is best and worst but with the caracteristic they have exemple : 
student 1 : 10 in maths 19 in science 
student 2 : 10 in science 19 in maths 
student 3 : 10 in science 19 in maths but is in lower class than student 2
the professor of science will see  first student 1 ten studient 2 
professor of maths will see first student 2 then student 3 then 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm relatively new to machine learning but in your scenario I'd use logistic regression since you are classifying the report cards in terms of best and worst.

Hope I have been of help